# Using HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> to classify numbers, but the set misses the first value

Tags: java

Given an array of integers say,

```
integers[] = {1, 2, 1, 7, 2};
```

I plan to use the following code to return a Map with the array element as the key and the indexes of that element as the value.

e.g., in this case, we will return:

```
1 -> (0,2)
2 -> (1,4)
7 -> (3)
```

But it does not quite work - the initial values added to the set aren't appearing. Here is the code:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<>();
for ( int k=0; k<integers.length; k++) { 
    Integer key=integers[k]; 
    if (hm.containsKey(key))
        hm.get(key).add(k);
    else
        hm.put(key, new HashSet<Integer>(k));
}
```

Comment: The code looks alright for the problem as stated. What problem are you facing? What result do you get on running this code?

Answer (score 6):

Your code won't work because this code:

```
hm.put(key, new HashSet(k));
```

doesn't do what you think it does. [That constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(int)) doesn't accept an initial *element*, it accepts the initial *size*.

Do this instead:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<>();
for (int k=0; k<integers.length; k++){ 
    Integer key=integers[k]; 
    if (!hm.containsKey(key))
        hm.put(key, new HashSet<>());
    hm.get(key).add(k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Bohemian correctly said, you weren't using HashSet's constructor properly.

Regarding the problem you posted, an alternative solution would be to use Guava's [HashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) class:

```
int integers[] = {1, 2, 1, 7, 2};
Multimap hm = HashMultimap.create();
for (int k = 0; k < integers.length; k++) { 
    Integer key = integers[k]; 
    hm.put(key, k);
}
Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> result = hm.asMap();
```